# Adding diacritics to Tibetan mantras with LaTeX

Tags: fonts, letters, indic

Thank you *very* much for your quick and skilled answers to my first question! Unfortunately they didn't solve my problem exactly, so I become more precise in my question: I'm working on an German translation of a commentary of a Tibetan meditation practise and want to add some expressions and mantras in Tibetan writing and tried the well elaborated `ctib` package. The great thing about this `ctib` package is the ability to write in well-known WYLIE transcription system. But for certain Mantras I need to put either the `\tibSnaldan` sign (part of `ctib`)  (actually this one mainly over the Tibetan letter Hung)  or just the small circle (...there is also a Sign defined in `ctib`, but don't know it at the moment, `\tibRangjasso` or something like this, but any small circle is fine...) *over* certain Tibetan letters like ba, ma, su, bu, ha and some more. It would be so great if someone could show me a solution!

Comment: Could you please provide us with some code. Show what you have and a little image of what you want to have and explain, what you have tried. Most of us are not familiar with Tibetan language and `ctib` and WYLIE are foreign words to me. You should also tell us, if you would be willing to use Xe/Lua-LaTeX. Thank you.

Comment: Please can you add an image of what you want exactly? Also why WYLIE and not extended wylie scheme? Can http://www.thlib.org/reference/transliteration/wyconverter.php give correct answers? Please be more explicit as to why not Unicode and XeLaTeX or LaTeX.

Comment: I use the public system sharelatex.com Ok, here some code: Include the package ctib and write the text in the main part: \tib{bu \tibRjessungaro}

Comment: ... the question on that is: how can I get the circle ON TOP of the syllable bu?

Comment: ... same with \tib{bu \tibSnalden}

Comment: The thlib wyconverter might indeed be a solution! Thank you a lot for that link!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the wylie transliteration, you could use the vertical stacking command in `ctib` to compose characters vertically like so `\tib{\V{\tibRjessungaro}{bu}}` which produces: [image]

If there is a unicode codepoint for the character (or sequences) you might be able to define them as [special characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQlk.png).

If you can compose the characters with another inuput method (or using a [online transliterator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters)), you should be able to include them directly in your .tex file and render using XeTeX.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  The idea with the online transliterator might be a solution! But getting it done with (extended) Wylie in Latex itself would be the best solution!

Comment: try something like `\tib{\V{\tibRjessungaro}{bu}}`